# Where does the Geonames admin_code1 for Russia come from?

Tags: region, geonames, russia

Looking at the data dump of post codes for Russia ([country downloads](https://download.geonames.org/export/dump/) | [Russian download link](https://download.geonames.org/export/dump/RU.zip)) I can't understand what the `admin_code1` corresponds to.

Looking at the ISO3166 sub regions, I see the codes are characters (whereas in geonames the codes are numeric).  Looking at Wikipedia I can't find a numeric reference for regions anywhere.  I was tempted to order alphabetically and take the row number, but some numbers are missing (2 for example).

In the `readme.txt` geonames lists `admin_code1`  as: `1. order subdivision (state) varchar(20)`, but this is just generic to all countries and gives no source.  I've also checked the [Russia page](https://www.geonames.org/countries/RU/russia.html), which links to the [St. Petersburg's administrative website](https://www.gov.spb.ru/), but there's seemingly nothing useful here.

What do the numbers here represent?  I need to link the ISO 3166 subdivisions to the countries in geonames, thus I need to create a lookup, is there an existing resource, or way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they're FIPs codes. See: https://download.geonames.org/export/dump/admin1CodesASCII.txt for a mapping to name. I think https://www.geonames.org/RU/administrative-division-russia.html gives you a mapping to ISO3166.